# How to tweak verts while in Anotate tool active?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, annotation

In this video retopology is done with addon b-surface using annotation to create mesh, https://youtu.be/FkWvgT75SbA?t=793 at 13:13 he moves vertices while having Annotate tool active. Bottom left corner says the key pressed is EVT_TWEAK_R but i don't know what it is. I am using the default keymap of blender and the tips on bottom show call menu for me instead of select and move like in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use right-click for selection in the video. It's a preference setting:
 *Preferences... → Keymap → Preferences section → Select with Mouse Button <kbd>left</kbd> / <kbd>right</kbd>*.

With right-click for selection you can use the *Annotation* tool with the left mouse button, and drag vertices around with the right mouse button. In *Selection* mode, new vertices can be extruded with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left-click. The context menu is opened with the <kbd>W</kbd> key.

Video: [Right Click Select - Blender 2.80 Fundamentals](https://youtu.be/REn2dBBy2mY)